# Azure Webapp PHP container HTTP 500, 502 on image files and favicon

Tags: docker, apache, http, azure-web-app-service, containers

Azure webapp Docker container with Microsoft php 7.3 image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/oryx/php:7.3-20190708.2
LABEL maintainer="Azure App Services Container Images <appsvc-images@microsoft.$

The website serve php, html, css , js ,txt successfully

(png,webp,woff2,ttf,ico,jpg)  gets http 500 and 502.
The weird thing i used to get 500 error on one webapp. I created another with the same exact container, and settings but get 502 on the other instance.

Tried many things but no look.

file permissions are same as PHP files which returns  HTTP 200

Log shows that apache have served the file with code 200 on both instances
[apache request log on both instances, browser returns 500,and 502](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeYse.jpg)

in the first instance with HTTP 500 error i get the following message after request
[Failed to forward request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi7kw.png)

Tried:

- adding FilesMatch , Require all granted. but since the log is returning 200 it does not seem to be apache problem
- removed AccessFileName .htaccess from apache.conf
- changed user and group from apache2.conf to nobody:nogroup  as it was shown in ssh ls- l

This error is making me crazy, it seems it is related to Azure front end  but don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

That can be solved by modifying apache2.conf file section in Dockerfile disabling MMAP and SendFile. More information here: https://azureossd.github.io/2020/09/15/unable-to-download-static-content-php-on-azure-app-service-linux/index.html

```
RUN { \
   echo 'DocumentRoot /home/site/wwwroot'; \
   echo 'DirectoryIndex default.htm default.html index.htm index.html index.php hostingstart.html'; \
   echo 'ServerName localhost'; \
   echo 'CustomLog /dev/stderr combined'; \

# IMAGES FIX
   echo 'EnableMMAP Off'; \
   echo 'EnableSendFile Off'; \
# IMAGES FIX
} >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```